# How to fix "ExecuteNonQuery:CommandText property has not been initialized?" error?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

I am getting an error ,

> "ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized"

Please help !!! I have been executing this code to save data in my other forms with our any error but when i try to use this with image save its giving me this error.

```
 Sub Save_Employee()
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    Dim comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
    comm.Connection = conn
    conn.Open()

    Dim str As String = "INSERT INTO Employee_Tbl VALUES (@RegNo,@FullName,@Country,@Occupation,@WorkSite,@DOB,@Photo,@Remarks,@Status)"
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegNo", RegNo_TextBox.Text)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", FullName_TextBox.Text)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", Country_ComboBox.Text)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occupation", Occupation_ComboBox.Text)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkSite", WorkSite_TextBox.Text)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", DOB_DateTimePicker.Text)

    Try
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        Dim bmpImage As New Bitmap(myimage.Image)

        bmpImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        bytImage = ms.ToArray()
        ms.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", bytImage)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", Remarks_TextBox.Text)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", Status_ComboBox.Text)
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("Saved successful!", "Employee Created", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you executing the command `comm.ExecuteNonQuery()` twice?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `CommandText` property before `comm.ExecuteNonQuery()`

```
comm.CommandText = str 
comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code might help you.

```
Sub Save_Employee()
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    Dim comm As SqlCommand
    Dim str As String

    Try
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        Dim bmpImage As New Bitmap(myimage.Image)

        bmpImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        bytImage = ms.ToArray()
        ms.Close()
        str = "INSERT INTO Employee_Tbl VALUES (@RegNo,@FullName,@Country,@Occupation,@WorkSite,@DOB,@Photo,@Remarks,@Status)"
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegNo", RegNo_TextBox.Text)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", FullName_TextBox.Text)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", Country_ComboBox.Text)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occupation", Occupation_ComboBox.Text)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkSite", WorkSite_TextBox.Text)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", DOB_DateTimePicker.Text)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", bytImage)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", Remarks_TextBox.Text)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", Status_ComboBox.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MS.Close()
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)

        str = "INSERT INTO Employee_Tbl VALUES (@RegNo,@FullName,@Country,@Occupation,@WorkSite,@DOB)"
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegNo", RegNo_TextBox.Text)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", FullName_TextBox.Text)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", Country_ComboBox.Text)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occupation", Occupation_ComboBox.Text)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkSite", WorkSite_TextBox.Text)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", DOB_DateTimePicker.Text)
    End Try

    Try
        conn.Open()
        comm = New SqlCommand(str, conn)
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Saved successful!", "Employee Created", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        conn.Close()
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```